# When I installed Ubuntu my windows 8.1 does not load?

Tags: 12.04, boot, windows-8, playonlinux

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop with win 8.1,but now when I start the power only **Ubuntu is come in DOS** and **the win 8.1 does not load**.
how I fix it?

Comment: Did you preserve the Windows 8.1 installation, or did you end up wiping it away and using the full hard drive for Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what exactly you did as @dobey asked above? This would give others a better idea.

Comment: Did you select the option to "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" upon installation?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) which attempts to automatically fix common booting problems (such as the one you're having). However, you'll need to run it on a Boot Disk.